# Improve accuracy of scaling down image

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm using Python 2.7 and PIL (pillow)

I have a script that takes fairly rough images of a maze and makes a cleaner, smaller image. Sample input and output:

[image: Sample]

Which was generated from this image:

[image: This one]

In that case, the script didn't work perfectly, but worked pretty well.

However, [another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ5Nd.jpg) of the same maze produced this result:

[image: less good]

That's less good.

I'm generating the images displayed side-by-side by looking at average values for each square on the 16x16 grid, then deciding if the square represents mostly black or mostly white pixels. However, since the perspective transformation isn't perfect, the squares aren't always lined up.

Are there any algorithms that would help with accuracy? Any way to look at squares of the grid that aren't perfectly square chunks?

A piece of my code:

```
#This image is already transformed and thresholded, like the first half of my side-by-side images
thresh = Image.open('Thresholded_Image.jpg')
pixsize = thresh.size[0]/16
segments = []
for i in range(16):
    for j in range(16):
        box = (j*pixsize,i*pixsize,(j+1)*pixsize,(i+1)*pixsize)
        segments.append(thresh.crop(box))
def blackWhite(image):
    '''Return `True` if the image is mostly white, else `False`'''
    l=image.convert('L').load()
    w,h=image.size
    lums=sum([[l[x,y] for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)],[])
    return sum(lums)/float(len(lums))>127
whites = []
for y in range(16):
    for x in range(16):
        seg = segments[16*y+x]
        if blackWhite(seg):
            whites.append((x,y))

maze = Image.new('L',(16,16))
l=maze.load()
for w in whites:
    x,y=w
    l[x,y] = 255
```

Comment: Can you copy the code that you're currently using so we can help troubleshoot it?

Comment: Sure. I'll put it in.

Comment: Consider weighting pixels that are near the center of the square you're evaluating more heavily, and those towards the edges less - that will help combat small misalignment. You could also try to locate the corners and then adjust the image so that the corners form a perfect square to help combat skew.

Comment: @Amber I'll try this. Seems promising.

Comment: @Fawful I put it in.

Comment: For some reason, the unwarping algorithm seems to crop the bottom row too early, so that a part is missing. Try to fix that. In any case, ensure that the whole maze is kept (keep the red corners), so that you can fine-locate the maze edges (which you cannot do when a part is cropped out).

Comment: @Amber please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*(As requested, reposting comment as answer.)*</sub>

Consider weighting pixels that are near the center of the square you're evaluating more heavily, and those towards the edges less - that will help combat small misalignment. You could also try to locate the corners and then adjust the image so that the corners form a perfect square to help combat skew.